# Syncfusion - No Space-Char after pressing shortcuts "CTRL" + "SPACE"

Tags: winforms, autocomplete, event-handling, syncfusion, editcontrol

We are using EditControl(component from the toolbox) from Syncfusion framework Essential Studio to write a small code-editor.
We want to popup the auto-complete window after pressing the shortcut **CTRL** + **SPACE** without typing the space-char into the EditorWindow.

Is there any way to disable typing characters into the EditControl?

```
Private Sub editControl1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        If e.Control Then
        ' Do something here
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
                EditControl1.ShowContextChoice()
                Dim context = EditControl1.ContextChoiceController
                For Each item As IConfigLexem In lexeme
                    context.Items.Add((item).BeginBlock, CStr(m_MethodComments(item.ID)), Me.EditControl1.ContextChoiceController.Images("Image" & item.FormatName))
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.Handled = true`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up key bindings within the control which will prevent you needing to trap the `KeyDown` event.

For example, create some `Sub` where you configuring the properties of the control (called `Editor` in my example) and add these lines:

```
AddHandler Editor.Commands.Add("Editor.ContextChoice").ProcessCommand, AddressOf Editor.ShowContextChoice

Editor.KeyBinder.BindToCommand(Keys.Control Or Keys.Space, "Editor.ContextChoice")
```

Check your install for a working example of this functionality. It is a good idea to elect to install the samples as they are very comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for ur response and the example how to do that with bindings.
But it is still typing the space-char into the text-field.